# не работает скрипт на python2.7

Tags: python, pil

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

from PIL import Image

imageFile = '/foto.jpg'
size = 600, 600
quality = 100
im = Image.open(imageFile)
im.thumbnail(size, Image.NEAREST)
im.save('/foto2.jpg', quality=quality)

print 'Content-type: text/html'
print ''         
print 'ok'
```

вот такая ошибка:

```
im.save('/foto2.jpg', quality=quality)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1932, in save
fp = builtins.open(filename, "w+b")
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/foto2.jpg'
```

в чём может быть дело?

Comment: У пользователя, под которым запускается скрипт, нет прав на запись в корень файловой системы.

Comment: скрипт запускается через браузер по ссылке

Comment: в консоле проверил, работает

Comment: а как сделать чтоб через браузер работал? я разворачиваю cgi сервер, вот так: python2.7 -m CGIHTTPServer

Comment: кстати после запуска в консоле, проверил картинку, размер не увеличился

Answer (score 1):

могу порекоментовать убрать слеш. на пайтоне, при работе с файлами в тойже дириктории слеши не нужны. если файл в другом каталоге, тогда нужно указывать полный путь к файлу

Comment: и с слешем и без, одинаковая ошибка